# How to copy range from an unactive workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, copy-paste, range

I'm simply trying to copy and paste between workbooks in VBA without first activating each workbook that I want to perform actions on.

My code stores the active workbook and sheet in variables before creating a new workbook after which cell A1 from the original workbook is supposed to be copied to the newly created one.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim pLWB As Workbook
Dim pLWS As Worksheet

Set pLWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set pLWS = ActiveSheet

Workbooks.Add

pLWB.pLWS.range("A1").copy

End Sub
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong? I was under the impression that you can refer to very specific cells through `workbooks.worksheets.range` but even as I was typing, the intellisense menu did not show `pLWS` as an option.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You need to open the source WB

Comment: @Raystafarian Do you mean open or active? Both the workbooks are open.

Comment: Well that's not included in your code. I have no idea what the variables should be or what is `active`

Comment: @Raystafarian Apologies, I already have one workbook open which is active. This active workbook and sheet is stored in the pL variables after which a new workbook is created.

Comment: Please include all of the code

Comment: @Raystafarian Edited my original question with the full code. The last line is giving me a "Object doesn't support this property out method" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the sheet differently - it's just one of those things.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim pLWB As Workbook
Dim pLWS As Worksheet

Set pLWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set pLWS = pLWB.ActiveSheet

Workbooks.Add

pLWS.Range("A1").Copy

End Sub
```

Also this works -

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim pLWB As Workbook
Dim pLWS As String

Set pLWB = ActiveWorkbook
 pLWS = ActiveSheet.Name

'Workbooks.Add

pLWB.Sheets(pLWS).Range("A1").Copy

End Sub
```